# ¿como añadir etiqueta de verificacion en web de google sites?

Tags: google-sites, insertar

he creado una pagina con google sites y quiero indexarla en google.
Me gustaria poder insertar la etiqueta del código de verificación pero no se como añadirlo en el punto correcto.
Agradeceria ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido @marsus. Que has intentado? Si no puedes poner código (perfectamente comprensible siendo google sites) explicanos un poco más tu problema, lo que tienes hecho, y lo que te falta hacer. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.